# How to constrain a View below two Views whose visibility can be switched?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Image a `ConstraintLayout` which includes three vertically stacked items:

```
@+id/top
@+id/middle1 or @+id/middle2 (one gets View.VISIBLE, one gets View.GONE)
@+id/bottom
```

The top of `@+id/middle1` and `@+id/middle2` is constrained to the bottom of `@+id/top`, no issue here.

The interesting case is `@+id/bottom`. That shall always be placed below `@+id/middle1` or `@+id/middle2`, depending on which one is visible (the other will get `View.GONE`). Is there any way to model this in the layout file or do I have to change the top constraint for `@+id/bottom` while switching between showing `@+id/middle1` and `@+id/middle2`?

Comment: Try setting up a `Barrier` to the bottom edge of `middle1` and `middle2`, then constrain the top of `bottom` to that `Barrier`.

Comment: As a generic response which works nearly universally w.r.t the layout engine, you could also just put `middle1` and `middle2` inside a `middlecontainer` view. Thus, the `middlecontainer` simply represents the relative space which the middle content occupies, whereas `middle1` or `middle2` represent the current content actually occupying that space. `bottom` would then be placed below `middlecontainer`. That being said, different layout engines also offer other methods of accomplishing the same task, sometimes in a cleaner way, such as barriers (as CommonsWare mentioned)

Comment: @CommonsWare that worked great, at least after I found out that referencing groups from barriers leads to no error message, but simple doesnt work. one needs to directly reference the single views. Can you post as answer?

Comment: @Nerdizzle Thanks, that's what I also thought about, but this increases layout complexity and your layout won't be flat anymore. So I am glad that at least for `ConstraintLayout` there's an optimized solution for that :-)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: If you got it to work, I recommend that you answer your own question, since you have working code in front of you, and I do not. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare done. now I was forced to steal you points ):

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As proposed by CommonsWare, it can be done with a `Barrier` as follows:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
          android:id="@+id/barrier"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:barrierDirection="bottom"
          app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"
          app:constraint_referenced_ids="middle1,middle2" />
```

Note that the IDs in `app:constraint_referenced_ids` are written without the `@id/` prefix.

As my `middle1` and `middle2` have different heights and I set one of them to `View.GONE`I went with `app:barrierAllowsGoneWidgets="false"` to make sure that the `Barrier` position gets updated and no blank space is left over.

For more details see the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/Barrier#allowsGoneWidget()) or e.g. on Youtube the video [ConstraintLayout Tutorial Part 4 - BARRIERS AND GROUPS - Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ngz5cgLC7m4)

Comment: Thanks you man, it's working as expected